# Why we have for any choice of descent direction $s_n$, the (n+1)th iterate obtained with exact line search satisfies $\nabla f(x_{n+1}).s_n=0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Why we have for any choice of descent direction $s_n$, the (n+1)th iterate obtained with exact line search satisfies $\nabla f(x_{n+1}).s_n=0$ ?

I don't see why they should be orthogonal at all.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If $t^*$ minimizes $g(t)=f(x_n + t s_n)$, then $g'(t^*)=0$. Use the chain rule to show that $g'(t^*) = \nabla f(x_n + t^* s_n) \cdot s_n$.